# What does m/n = m'/n' iff mn'=m'n mean when talking about Rational numbers in Infinite sets?

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

[image: Question]

I couldn't find anything anywhere about what this condition stated meant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the equivalence relation defining *fraction equality,* e.g. $\ 1/3= 2/6\ $ by $\, 1\cdot 6 = 2\cdot 3\ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Definition**: A *pre-rational number* is a tuple $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$.

**Definition**: Two pre-rational numbers $(m,n)$ and $(m^\prime,n^\prime)$ are said to be *equivalent* if $mn^\prime = m^\prime n$. In this case, we write $(m,n) \sim (m^\prime,n^\prime)$.

**Exercise:** $\sim$ is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

**Definition**: We define the *rational numbers* as the [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Notation_and_formal_definition) $\mathbb{Q} \equiv (\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}))\,\,/\sim$.

Now, instead of writing $[(m,n)]$ to denote a member of $\mathbb{Q}$, it is common practice to write instead $a/b$, where $(a,b)\in [(m,n)]$.